# Spring: Could not determine type for: java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following scenario:
I have a Student class and `students` table.
I have Course class and `courses` table.
Every student and course have unique ID.
I would like to put a List into the Student class which is mapped by courses IDs.

I have tried a lot of annotations and relations but nothing succeeded

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Course() {

    }

    public Course(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

Can you help me hot to achieve that because i am a little newbie into the spring

Comment: You can look for one to many uni-directional mapping.

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private List < Course > courses = new ArrayList < Course > ();

Comment: nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: students, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(courses)]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following when declaring one to many relation

```
@Column(name="course_id")
private Set<Course> courses;
```

Comment: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: students, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(courses)]

Comment: Try Column instead of JoinColumn

Comment: Again the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OneToMany annotation.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "students", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Course> courses;
```

Comment: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: students, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(courses)]

Comment: Isn't it Many to Many relation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your list a type. For instance 
`List<Courses> courseList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks but again the same exception